# How do I make just one UL element undraggable in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using the draggable jquery sdk and I want to make just one of the UL members undraggable and everything else draggable as per the [jQuery UI photo manager demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#photo-manager).

For example I want to make the first photo not draggable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of:

```
$( "li", $gallery ).draggable
```

selector, use this one:

```
$( "li:gt(0)", $gallery ).draggable
```

- [:gt() docs](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/)

Comment: How do I do this in HTML?  I am manually creating the LI in HTML and want to flag the first one as nondraggable

Answer (score 1):

As seen in the [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#option-cancel)

```
$( ".selector" ).draggable({ cancel: ".special" });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want undraggable element just use [`not`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector:

```
$( "li:not(.notdragabble)" ).droppable();
```

---

If you want notaccepted element:

Use [`accept`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#option-accept) option and [`not`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector:

```
$( ".selector" ).droppable({ accept: "not(.notdragabble)" });
```

HTML for example:

```
<ul>
   <li>sdfsdf</li>
   <li>sdfsdf</li>
   <li class="notdragabble">sdfsdf</li>   
</ul
```

Comment: This doesn't make it non-draggable, it just makes it non-accepting when you try to drop it...

Answer (score 0):

When you specify something as draggable you apply the draggability to a jQuery object. In the example of the link you sent they have:

```
$( "li", $gallery ).draggable([options]);
```

All you need to do to make something not draggable is ensure that your selector in the jQuery contains onyl those you want to be draggable. the easiest way being to put a class called "draggable" or something on the items you want to be draggable.